# Does "Don't talk. Your mouth is full." sound natural?

Tags: phrase-choice, sentence-choice

He likes to talk while he eating.

> "Don't talk with your mouth full."
>
> "Don't talk. Your mouth is full."

Does the second sentence sound natural to a native speaker?

Comment: Nope. Our moms always told us "Don't talk with your mouth full!"

Comment: Don't talk when you are eating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the second sentence has no grammatical errors, yet, it's not the common way to say it. The everyday phrase is:

- Don't talk with your mouth full.